Why is from_box_in(src: Box<T, A>) -> Rc<T, A> implemented this way in the rust std lib?
In Rusts standard library, Rc::from_box_in copies the memory, why not just do it like.
fn foo<T>(box_val: Box<T>) -> Rc<T> {
    let val_ptr = &*box_val as *const T;
    let rc_val: Rc<T> = unsafe { Rc::from_raw(val_ptr) };
    rc_val
}

I have not found any problem with this impl;

I don't see from_box_in in the standard library. Can you clarify where you saw it or provide it's implementation?

Regardless, Rc::from_raw is unsafe and documents that the pointer passed to it must have been obtained by Rc::into_raw. Your implementation violates that. Rc needs additional bookkeeping data to track handles that wouldn't be there from a simple Box.

@kmdreko Rc::from_box_in is defined in alloc, it's not a public function.

An RcBox<T> is not just T. In the current version on docs.rs:
#[repr(C)]
struct RcBox<T: ?Sized> {
    strong: Cell<usize>,
    weak: Cell<usize>,
    value: T,
}

Note two counts (as cells) and the value.
Further, note that Rc::from_raw calls Rc::from_raw_in, which subsequently does the following:
    pub unsafe fn from_raw_in(ptr: *const T, alloc: A) -> Self {
        let offset = unsafe { data_offset(ptr) };

        // Reverse the offset to find the original RcBox.
        let rc_ptr = unsafe { ptr.byte_sub(offset) as *mut RcBox<T> };

        unsafe { Self::from_ptr_in(rc_ptr, alloc) }
    }

The original RcBox is found by pointer arithmetic. If that pointer wasn't pointing into the data field of an RcBox (and a raw pointer into a normal box does not point into the data field of an RcBox), then this is simply unsound, as it transmutes a wayward pointer into a pointer to an RcBox, then returns an Rc with that pointer. As soon as you use that Rc in any meaningful way, an invalid &RcBox-not-referencing-a-real-RcBox is produced.
On the other hand, from_box_in (with the current implementation), does a bytewise copy, and then frees the original box allocation without calling drop glue on the contents, which is what we want. Essentially, it's manually performing something analogous to a rust move (which is just a bytewise copy) with the appropriate drop semantics.

I don't know where you got this code snippet. There is no public function in std called from_box_in. And moreover it is UB to call Rc::from_raw on a pointer taken from Box.
However the general question "why is copying data necessary?" has pretty easy solution. Box and Rc have incompatible data layouts. Box have a layout of *const T, which points to a heap allocated T (this is simplification, but a useful one). Meanwhile Rc has a layout of *const RcBox, which points to a heap allocated data and Rc counters. It is defined as:
#[repr(C)]
struct RcBox<T: ?Sized> {
    strong: Cell<usize>,
    weak: Cell<usize>,
    value: T,
}

So if you have an allocation of T, you cannot change it in any way to an allocation of RcBox<T>. You have to allocate new RcBox first, then copy the value (which has an offset of 2 words in RcBox), and then dealocate original Box.
